# Memory spike when reading multiple image files

Tags: c#, image, winforms, memory, thumbnails

I'm trying to make a file explorer and one issue I have been stuck on is trying to fix a memory spike that occurs when i load multiple thumbnails from images. Here is the section that I believe it is in (This is all wrapped in a background worker):

```
static string[] imageType = new string[] { "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp" };

List<string> filesList = new List<string>();

foreach (FileInfo file in fileList)
    filesList.Add(file.FullName);

string[] files = filesList.ToArray();

NumericComparer nc = new NumericComparer();
Array.Sort(files, nc);

foreach (string file in files)
{
    Application.OpenForms["MDC_Explorer"].Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }));

    Panel d = new Panel();
    d.Size = new Size(parent.Width / 5 - 10, 100);//Image Height: 70px
    d.Location = new Point(left, top);
    d.Tag = file;
    d.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(item_MouseEnter);
    d.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(item_MouseLeave);
    d.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

    Label l = new Label();
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
    l.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.FullName);
    l.Size = new Size(d.Width, 25);
    l.Location = new Point(0, 75);
    l.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
    l.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 90, 90, 90);
    l.Font = new Font(parent.Font.FontFamily, 10, FontStyle.Regular);
    l.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    l.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(item_MouseEnter);
    l.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(item_MouseLeave);
    l.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(item_MouseClick);

    d.Controls.Add(l);

    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

    string path = file;

    if (Path.GetExtension(file).Replace(".", "") == "lnk")
    {
        IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell shell = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell();
        IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut link = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(file);
        path = link.TargetPath;
    }

    if (!File.Exists(path) && path.Contains("Program Files (x86)"))
        path = path.Replace("Program Files (x86)", "Program Files");

    Bitmap bmp = Path.GetExtension(path).Replace(".", "") == "exe" ? Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path).ToBitmap() : (imageType.Contains(Path.GetExtension(path).Replace(".", "")) ? new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path))), new Size(d.Width - 20, 80)) : new Bitmap(GetLargeIconForExtension(Path.GetExtension(path)).ToBitmap()));
            bigThumbnail.Add(bmp);

    int fp = (parent.Width / 4) * 3 - 50;
    smallThumbnail.Add(new Bitmap(bmp, new Size((fp / 5), 80)));

    pb.BackgroundImage = bmp;
    pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
    pb.Size = new Size(d.Width - 20, 80);
    pb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    pb.Location = new Point(10, 10);
    pb.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(item_MouseEnter);
    pb.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(item_MouseLeave);
    pb.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(item_MouseClick);

    d.Controls.Add(pb);

    if (left + (d.Width * 2) + 5 >= parent.Width)
    {
        top += d.Height + 5;
        left = 5;
    }
    else
        left += d.Width + 5;

    Application.OpenForms["MDC_Explorer"].Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        parent.Controls.Add(d);
    }));
}
```

Sorry if I provided to much code but I believe the error is where it gets the thumbnail and puts it into a bitmap but I am unsure how to lower the memory usage.

Comment: what exactly is your end goal(or better,design goal)?

Comment: How much were you expecting memory usage to increase by?

Comment: End Goal: Decrease memory usage so it can run on lower system specs.
I don't get what you mean but it goes from about 30k to 200k when grabbing the thumbnails.

Comment: This might be better fit on codereview unless it's causing out of memory exceptions...

Comment: "...(or better,design goal)?"...

Comment: You are loading *maybe* a ton of pictures, so it's normal the memory raises. If you want to do it efficiently then don't load all the images at once, load them when they become visible to the user  and unload them when they become hidden(if you enter a folder with a thousand images you are not showing all of them, so load only when the picturebox becomes visible and when it goes offscreen then dispose it again)

Comment: It doesn't look like you're cleaning up any resources after you've pushed the bitmap onto the control.

Comment: @terrybozzio The design goal is to make it easier for the user to use and navigate without impairing the system or it's functionality.

Comment: @Gusman That's the thing... the memory only raises while its loading the thumbnail from the image file. Once it's put it into a picture box the memory goes back to normal (although slightly higher).

Comment: Well, then it's normal, the app is loading the full image, creating an scaled one an then disposing the full one, you cannot avoid that... how "big" is that memory spike? 1-5Mb?

Comment: @Gusman No it jumps up about 200Mb when loading about 40 images (so about 5Mb/image).

Comment: Then it's normal, it's just because the garbage collector still did not claimed all the memory used by those images. If you want to control the memory allocation then don't use the functions result as-is, add them to variables and Dispose() as it should, I'm going to write a response with how it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating Images and Bitmaps without disposing them, so until the garbage collector destroys those bmp's they are in memory.

Also, in some cases you are reading all the image file in memory, loading it into an stream and then passing it to Image.FromStream, is a lot better to just do Image.FromFile.

Instead of:

```
Bitmap bmp = Path.GetExtension(path).Replace(".", "") == "exe" ?     
Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path).ToBitmap() : 
(imageType.Contains(Path.GetExtension(path).Replace(".", "")) ? new 
Bitmap(Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path))), 
new Size(d.Width - 20, 80)) : new Bitmap(GetLargeIconForExtension(Path.GetExtension(path))
.ToBitmap()));
```

do this:

```
        Bitmap bmp;

        string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);

        if (ext == ".exe")
        {

            Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path);
            bmp = ico.ToBitmap();
            ico.Dispose();

        }
        else
        {

            if (imageType.Contains(ext.Replace(".", "")))
            {

                Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
                bmp = new Bitmap(img, new Size(d.Width - 20, 80));
                img.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {

                Icon ico = GetLargeIconForExtension(ext);
                bmp = ico.ToBitmap();
                ico.Dispose();

            }

        }
```